# Woocommerce - set SKU to match Product ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We sync data from Woocommerce to Quickbooks, and we need all product SKUs to match the product IDs. I have built the following code to solve the problem:

```php
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_sku', 10,3 );

function set_sku( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Only want to set if this is a new post!
    if ( !$update ){
        return;
    }

    // Only set for post_type = post!
    if ( 'product' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    if( empty( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', true ) ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', $post_id );
    }
       
}
```

Is there a better way to code this? And is it possible to make it work for items created via CSV? Right now it only seems to work if I'm creating the item through the admin dashboard.